# Is there a query to remove duplicate from collection based on where condition in mysql?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am writing a query in rails. I have tables named School and Skill.
Skill has columns

```
id: integer
name: text 
school_id: integer
```

I have @skills which contains some rows. But @skills can have duplicate names.

I want to remove the duplicate rows from @skills where school_id==1.

For example, if @skills returns

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Skill id: 249, name: "3 D Priniting", school_id: 1>, 
  #<Skill id: 258, name: "Cinematography", school_id: 11>,
  #<Skill id: 174, name: "Sports", school_id: 1>, 
  #<Skill id: 259, name: "Cinematography", school_id: 1>, 
  #<Skill id: 300, name: "Sales", school_id: 11>, 
  #<Skill id: 301, name: "Marketing", school_id: 11>,]
```

Here Skill id 258 and 259 have the same name. So I want to remove 259 because it has school_id == 1.

I used the following SQL query, but it selects the MIN(id).

```
SELECT MIN(id) as id, school_id 
FROM `skills` 
GROUP BY `skills`.`tag_id`,  
`skills`.`tag_type`, `skills`.`school_id`, `skills`.`master_tag_id`
```

Can I remove the duplicate items this way? And I want to do this in a single query.

Note: Solution in ActiveRecord is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this query:

```
set @lagName := '';
set @rn := 0;
select id, name, school_id from (
  select 
    case when @lagName = name then @rn:=@rn+1 else @rn:=1 end rn,
    @lagName:=name,
    id,
    name,
    school_id
  from Skills
  order by name, school_id desc
) a where rn=1
```

It uses row nubering within groups based on `name` column. Each group then is sorted by `school_id` desceindingly, so `school_id` comes last. Then it's enough to pick those records with `rn` equal to one.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from skills where id in (select MIN(id) from skills group by  name);
```

Comment: Max(Id) will include Skill row id 259. Use min(id) to exclude it from the sub query result

Comment: @AnanthCool Ohh sorry, it was by mistake, thanks for correcting me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Subquery method.First group @skills table using Schol_id and name. Then excute actual select statement.

```
select * from skills where id in (select id from skills group by school_id, name);
```